# No me cargan las variables!

Tags: php, laravel

En mi proyecto de laravel tengo un problemilla! estoy ocupando 2 variables que recibo desde una view desde livewire, las 2 variables las paso para ocuparlas en otra función, pero, me da un error que dice

> ArgumentCountError
> PHP 8.1.2
> 9.17.0
> Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\GraficosController::index(), 0 passed in C:\Users\DOMOTICA\Desktop\domo - copia - copia\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 2 expected

Estoy tratando de resolverlo, pero, no entiendo, segun yo, está bien el código, no entiendo que pasa!

Les dejo parte del código! <3
De ante mano, muchas gracias

```
    public function index($informeSelect, $tipoInforme)
    {
        $informeSelect = $_POST['clasificacion']; //puede que se tenga que invertir xd
        $tipoInforme = $_POST['tipoInforme'];
}
```

Ese código no está completo, solo extraje lo necesario, en la otra función los tengo así, por cierto, están en la misma página.

```
    public function mostrarChartNorte()
    {
        $informeSelect = 1;
        $tipoInforme = 1;
        
        $datos_informe_select = $this->index($informeSelect, null);
        $datos_informe_tipo = $this->index($tipoInforme, null);
}
```

Los inicialicé en 1, pensé que ese era el problema!

Comment: Tu método `index` espera 2 argumentos, pero solo le estas pasando 1 (_null no cuenta_). Al ver el código que compartís, te diría que no tiene ningun sentido llamarlo desde el método `mostrarChartNorte` ¿para que le pasas datos si no devuelve nada? ¿por que lo llamas 2 veces si deberías llamarlo 1 y pasarle ambos datos?

Comment: Hay un query por debajo, en mostrarchartnorte!, ese query le da datos a las variables

Comment: Pero ahí no esta el problema. El problema es el método `index`... no tiene sentido. No hace nada. ¿Que se supone que debería hacer?

Comment: Puedes incluir la vista, para ver como estás pasando la variable desde la vista al controlador.?
Lo estas haciendo con wire:model? wire:emit? 

las variables debieras iniciarlas como 

public $variable = 1 
Fuera de la función.